# Defining an object based on parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm using a third party solution in my React app that expects an `options` object. I'm creating a helper function that will create and return this object for me.

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to create this object based on parameters passed to my helper function. If no parameter or a `null` value is received for certain properties, I want to omit them in my object.

What's the best way for me to create this object? One idea is to start with a basic object and then keep using `Object.assign()` to add or not add additional properties -- see below. I'd appreciate other and potentially cleaner/tidier suggestions.

```
export const getUser = (firstName, middleName, lastName, gender) => {

   let user = {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName
   };

   if(typeof middleName !== "undefined" && middleName !== null && middleName.length > 0) {

      user = Object.assign({}, user, {
         middleName: middleName
      });

   }

   return user;
};
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in syntax to conditionally define properties. The simplest way for adding the property would be

```
if (middleName) {
  user.middleName = middleName;
}
```

No need for `Object.assign` and creating unnecessary intermediate objects.

---

Or do it the other way round: Add everything and remove what's invalid.

```
const user = {
  firstName,
  middleName,
  lastName,
  gender,
};

for (const key of Object.keys(user)) {
  if (!user[key]) {
    delete user[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: So, the first approach, will add the property and its value, correct? If there's no value, I don't even want the property in the object. For example, if no middleName is provided, there should be no `middleName` property in my object.